# Lua parse and count a string

Tags: lua

so I have a string that is outputted and it contains little sub strings in it, so it's formated like so `"Glyph 1", "Glyph 19", "Glyph 22"`. What I want to do is to get a number of how many sub strings are in it. Now I know if it was a table that this would pretty easy, just put a '#' in front of it, but this is a string. I've tried using `gmatch` and `split` but gmatch seems to divide one string into sub strings and split just makes a table into a string containing sub strings. I'm sure there's some solution I've overlooked.

Comment: you could use a generic for loop with gmatch and count the matches but if you're not interested in the substrings themselves go with Leszek's solution. there is no `split` in native Lua

Answer (score 2):

You can get just second reply from gsub:

```
local _, quantity = string.gsub(myString, "%s*\"[^\"]+\"%s*,?", "")
```

Comment: I find your pattern a bit complicated. `'%b""'` would also do the job. or sub commas and add 1